# Fitting data to Gaussian Distribution: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (14,2)

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to fit data to a Gaussian Distribution and I keep getting this error:
return -sum(log(gaussian.pdf((z-a)/b)/b))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (14,2)

I don't know what I am missing.  Any ideas?  Thank you so much for your help!
Here is the code so far:

```
from pylab import *
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm as gaussian
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def main():
fname='HW4Q4data.csv'
data = loadtxt(fname, delimiter=',')
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
m =data.shape[0]

z = []
n = len(z)
for i in range(n):
    z += [x[i]]*y[i]
z = array(z)

def fit_likelihood(a,b):
    return -sum(log(gaussian.pdf((z-a)/b)/b))
objective = fit_likelihood(a,b)
result = fmin(objective, [67.,5.])
mu, sigma = result[0], result[1]
print ("Numerical Parameter fits: ", (mu, sigma))
print ("\tAverage Log-Likelihood: ", fit_likelihood(result,b)/n)

# fast, exact method
mu = sum(z)/float(n)
sigma = sqrt(sum((z-mu)**2)/n)
print ("Exact Parameter fits: ", (mu,sigma))
print ("\tAverage Log-Likelihood: ", fit_likelihood((mu,sigma))/n)
print ("\tn = : ", fit_likelihood((mu,sigma))/n)


u = linspace(min(z)*.95,max(z)*1.05, 256)
figure(1, figsize=(8,16))
subplot(3,1,1)

plt.plot(u, n*gaussian.pdf((u-mu)/sigma)/sigma, 'b-')
width = .3
bar_ob = bar(x-width*.5, y, width, color='k')
xlim(min(u), max(u))
ylabel('Count', fontsize=18)
title('Best Fit Gaussian: $\mu = %f$, $\sigma = %f$'%(mu,sigma), fontsize=18)
show()
```

main()

Comment: `objective = fit_likelihood(a, b)` assigns the value of the likelihood to `objective`. It's no longer a function, it's a scalar, so trying to "optimize" it doesn't make sense. Also, you should be able to use the `scipy.stats.norm.fit` method directly.

Comment: in order to expect help it would be helpful if you provided correct code - I'm afraid your indentation is off here which makes it tough to read.